# Extract data from list but not exact match on text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, office365, vlookup

I am trying to extract / filter a list of names based on if a player is attending. For example if Player A is FALSE not playing only show the last 3 pairs in the example below.

I have a list of names of players. Column A (Players) Column B (Attending T / F) I then have a list of pairs for example. Column D (Pairs not played)

[image]

I have tried a few different ways but cannot see a way round it. This is a sample data set. My actual data set has 20 Individual names and 40 pairs. At the end I'd like a list in F of possible pairs of players attending

I thought about using IF, IFERROR, VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH.

Any ideas?

Comment: So how did you get on using the functions you suggested?

Comment: @bigben I use both 365 and Google Sheets. Happy to amend if needed.

Comment: Ok, but which do you actually want a solution for? They are not identical.

Comment: @SolarMike I've tried =VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$D$40,2,0). It doesn't like it an not exact match.

Comment: @BigBen probably office365.

Comment: @JessSheasby you can check your Office Version from --> File --> Account --> On Right Side Product Information Microsoft --> Subscription Procut as Office 365 or the version you have.

Answer (score 0):

So, this works, but not sure if I can find a simpler method:

[image]

Note the first formula in cell B6 has changed:

```
IF(AND(C1=TRUE,C2=TRUE),B1&" "&B2,"")
```

The others are correct and the two missing are just B6 dragged down.

Comment: One can simplify `AND(C1=TRUE, C2=TRUE)` to just `AND(C1,C2)`, right?

Comment: @BigBen yes, but I left that to show the test just in case something like "yes" or "no" is wanted. I was thinking like a sumproduct() or similar...

Answer (score 0):

With the following Excel tables:

[Table1 and Table2 image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNsBE.jpg)

Table2[Assignable] formula:

```
=INDEX(Table2,MATCH([@Player1],Table2[Player],0),2)*INDEX(Table2,MATCH([@Player2],Table2[Player],0),2)
```

1 indicates both players present, 0 means one or both are absent.